# No prompt to accept files when Airdropped to myself?

Tags: macos, ios, icloud, airdrop

Ive just airdropped a file from my phone (iPhone 8, iOS 12.x) to my computer (MacBook Pro, OSX 10.13.x). Both devices use the same Apple / iCloud ID.

The file was received fine, but I was not required to confirm acceptance of the file on my computer. My concern is that someone could send me a file maliciously.

My computers AirDrop settings are set to "Allow me to be discovered by Contacts Only."

If another contact with a different Apple ID tried to Airdrop a file to my computer, would my computer ask me to accept it ?

Comment: This is happening to me on Mac OS Sonoma with iOS 16.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204144):

> If you AirDrop content to yourself, like share a photo from your iPhone to your Mac, **you won't see an option to Accept or Decline**. The content is automatically sent to that device. Just make sure that both devices are signed in with the same Apple ID.

AirDrop is working as designed.  I don't think you need to worry about someone sending you malicious content.

Comment: In my case (iPhone 13 iOS 15.4 to Mac mini M1 Monterey 12.3), if I have the AirDrop Finder page opened then I hear the sound of "downloading" stuff and the file is there in Download folder, while if I don't have the Airdrop page opened I hear the "Accept/Decline" sound but no notification and so the file is not there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your computer/ iPhone will ask to accept if another Apple ID sends something. I am not sure of Family Sharing.